# Where can I find that little arrow what was in the bottom right corner in older versions of Excel on macOS?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I am looking for this little arrow (sorry I am not sure about the name).

This is what it looks like:
[image: link 1]

This is what I am looking for
[image: link 2]

Comment: It appears you are comparing a Mac version to a Windows version. Please edit your question and/or tags to indicate you are using Mac OS X & its version as it might be helpful. It seems MS may have removed those arrows in pictures I am seeing

Comment: Yes, it seems they removed it, but I still have to be able to reach those settings somewhere else. I edited it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You appear to be using Excel for Mac of which it seems doesn't have those group-arrows :(](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dialog-box-launcher-missing/5cfeb09c-685a-458c-9b55-8fcf9e683743)

P.S. [The top is called the 'ribbon', each subsection called a group, & the arrow is called the 'dialog box launcher' per this MS article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/uxguide/cmd-ribbons)

Comment: Thank you for the information. Than the only way is Boot Camp.

Comment: The "Dialog Box launcher" on the Mac is called the Menu Bar and everything is there. For example the arrow in "Format" on the PC is in the menu "Format > Font" on the Mac or reachable by typing COMMAND-D.